# How to reduce flutter release apk size in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, apk, size, release

I have done this thing in android build.gradle and created proguard-android.txt file in app directory, but the thing is how to without any change in android file done. how to possible via pubspec.yaml file

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


proguard-rules.pro

#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```